# SQL IN() clause executes the column in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to execute a SQL query with IN() clause and the resultSet will return the dataType of the particular columns.

Assume, I have two columns named as **groupId** and **date**.

**groupId** is **textField** and **date** is **dateField**.

When I execute the below command,

```
select data_Type_Name from data_type where displayName in('groupId','date')
```

First, it returns the date dataType and then it returns groupId dataType.

But my expected result would be groupId dataType and date dataType. Which means, resultSet should return according to column names inside the IN() statement.

Kindly provide an idea to solve this scenario.

Comment: A [mcve] would really help

Comment: Without an ORDER BY clause the server my return the rows in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ORDER BY clause. Change your query to:

```
select data_Type_Name from data_type where displayName in('groupId','date')
ORDER BY displayName desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The more general method is to use `field()`:

```
select data_Type_Name
from data_type
where displayName in ('groupId', 'date')
order by field(displayName, 'groupId', 'date');
```

Alphabetic ordering happens to work for your particular case.  But that is not a general solution.